# Aptana 3, php code background highlighting

Tags: php, ide, aptana, aptana3

can somebody help to remove php code background highlighting in `Aptana 3.2.1`.

In earlier version of aptana 3 it was fine, now - all php code (in .php files) 
has highlighted background, and i can't find themes, appearance settings to change it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found setting in `Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes`, default Aptana Studio theme, needed to change style named - `Embedded Source`

Comment: The scope selector for `Embeded Source` is `text source` when it ought to be `text.source`