# Some line beginnings are a different color in Aptana

Tags: themes, aptana, color-scheme

I've spent like an hour tying to find a way to fix this, but I just can't do it. Some lines/characters will show up a different color in Aptana (all semicolons, some tabs, and some whole). I just installed it today, so I don't know my way around the software very well.

Here's a picture to help you get the idea:

[image]

I would like get rid of the way some sections are lighter (the line saying `some text` is the line the caret's on, which is not the problem)

P.S. If this is the wrong place to ask this, I'm sorry, but I'm getting frustrated searching through Google and the Aptana preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too spent way too much time on this issue.

The answer by phazei is correct:
[Aptana 3, php code background highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033197/aptana-3-php-code-background-highlighting)

But my main problem was I didn't know where to look. So to give some insight into how I found the answer:

It turns out you can see what markup the editor is using and how it classifies any block of text, by just right-clicking on the text you are interested in and pick Show in -> Properties.